# How to dynamically add gridviews side by side using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, panel

I am creating a page which shows some details in several gridviews. I am saying several because the number of gridviews is **not constant**. I am having a panel on the aspx page and adding gridviews to it dynamically.

aspx code:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlResult" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
```

aspx.cs code

```
int numOfGroups = some number here;
            for (int i = 1; i < numOfGroups + 1; i++)
            {
                GridView grd = new GridView();
                grd.ID = "GridView" + i.ToString();
                grd.BackColor = getColor(i);
                grd.DataSource = dt; // some data source
                grd.DataBind();
                pnlResult.Controls.Add(grd);
            }
```

But my problem is that the gridviews are adding **one below the another** . I want them to be side by side. How can I achieve that?

**Note: Panel is not mandatory. Anything else can be used in its place**

Comment: All the below answers work according to my requirements. However I am going with the float="left" just for the sake of simplicity.Also added margin-left to create gaps in between

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to `float` your elements inside the panel to `left`. To achieve that in your code behind, before adding grid to the panel do:

```
grd.Attributes.Add("class", "float-left");
```

Where `float-left` class in your css is defined as:

```
.float-left {
    float: left;
}
```

So your code would look like:

```
for (int i = 1; i < numOfGroups + 1; i++)
{
    GridView grd = new GridView();
    grd.ID = "GridView" + i.ToString();
    grd.BackColor = getColor(i);
    grd.Attributes.Add("class", "float-left"); //here
    grd.DataSource = dt; // some data source
    grd.DataBind();
    pnlResult.Controls.Add(grd);
}
```

Comment: your method works but I added margin-left in the class because otherwise the gridviews are stuck together

Comment: @nitinvertigo, yes you can add margin, or padding. Glad it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a table control, then you can create a row, and add each grid as cells, which would enforce the side-by-side requirement:

```
TableCell cell = new TableCell();
cell.Controls.Add(grd);

table.Rows(0).Cells.Add(cell);
```

Something like that; not sure if the Table API example above is 100% correct, but hopefully you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
Table tbl = new Table();
TableRow tr = new TableRow();
TableCell tc = new TableCell();

btn = new  Button();
        btn.Text = "Add ";
        btn.Height = Unit.Pixel(30);
        btn.Width = Unit.Pixel(100);

tc.Controls.Add(btn);

tr.Controls.Add(tc);
tbl.Controls.Add(tr);
panel.Controls.Add(tbl);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe u need just to add some css?
like that:

`grd.DataSource = dt; // some data source
    grd.Style["float"] = "left";  // css
    grd.DataBind();`